# Timeout in SSIS package running DBCC CHECKDB

Tags: sql-server, ssis, dbcc-checkdb, timeout, ssis-2014

I have created an SSIS package to run DBCC CHECKDB on all the databases on the server and send error messages by email.

But for several of the databases, I get an exception running my script:

> Timeout expired.
>   The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.

The only timeout I can find in the project/package is set to 0, which I presume means no timeout.

`DBCC CHECKDB` runs from SSMS just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, there is a CommandTimeout property on the SqlCommand object.